# wamp phpmyadmin scripts/setup.php not found, but is there

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I installed wampserver 2.2 on my windows 7 machine and it runs. So far so good.

Next thing was to get `localhost/phpmyadmin/` working, which it does now (added `localhost` to the `hosts` file). But then... I have a few php files that are in the `www` folder and when I run these as `localhost/whatevername.php`, then they all run fine.

However, if I want to go to `localhost/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php`, then my browser says that that file cannot be found. What am I missing? (it must be something silly....)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing a course and THEY say that that file exists.. but when I do a search for the file, it just simply does NOT exist AT ALL.
..which explains why it wouldn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the `setup.php` part...

i.e, use this one instead - `localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/`

that solved my problem. Good luck friend