# Can't access PHPmyadmin. my wamp server version 2.4

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost, wampserver

Can't access phpMyAdmin. My wampserver version is 2.4

localhost/phpmyadmin/

result:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

plz solution me

Comment: You need to change some user credentials in phpmyadmin configuration file so please have a look at these links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498343/putting-a-password-to-a-user-in-phpmyadmin-in-wamp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748947/wamp-phpmyadmin-scripts-setup-php-not-found-but-is-there

Comment: This is not related to MySQL credentials. It's a problem at the web-server level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the WAMPServer 2.4 release.

You should read this post [in English](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,118138) or this post [in French](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?1,116068) from the WAMPServer help forum.

This may well fix this problem, but if not please do read through and make the suggested change in the above document:

Edit `c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

Change

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
```

To

```
Require local
```

You should do this to the other 2 files in that folder as well especially if you plan to use `sqlbuddy` and/or `webgrind`